# Am I correct in evaluating this mathematical statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether this statement is $T$ or $F$, or whether this cannot be determined without knowledge of the value of $x$. If the truth value cannot be determined, show one example of a value of for which the claim is true, and one example for which the claim is false.

$$x<3\Leftrightarrow x<2$$

Steps I took:

I split this statement to see what happens when it goes in each direction as such:

$$x<3\Rightarrow x<2 \quad x<2\Rightarrow x<3$$

$x<3\Rightarrow x<2$ is indeterminate because $x$ can be $2.5$ or it can be $1$

$x<2\Rightarrow x<3$ is $T$ because anything less than $2$ has to be less than $3$.

Even though I think I might be right up till now, I don't know how to exactly organize my thoughts on this statement to come up with an answer.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You have written a biconditional statement correct?

Comment: @VarunIyer Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is this: if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x < 3$ iff $x < 2$. To disprove it, it suffices to point it out that there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that it is not true that $x < 3$ iff $x < 2$; for example $x := 2.5$, which is $<3$ and $>2$. This alone breaks the "iff"; recall that an "iff" statement is simply a mutual implication.

The string "$x < 3$ iff $x < 2$" of symbols is meaningless; its truth value is variable, and it is not considered as a sentence in mathematics.

Comment: So then this statement can't be proven true nor false. Right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes! So I restate it in the first place. :)

Comment: @Cherry_Developer technically yes, because as I showed in my answer, if you let $x$ take on a range of different values, then the truth value will be variable, and there will be no strictly defined answer.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: A rule of thumb is to notice that every meaningful statement in mathematics has the form "every object is so-and-so" or the form "some object is so-and-so"; that is why quantifiers are important in mathematics.

Comment: Considering the final statement that you made, I assume that this means I have to just show one value for $x$ so that the claim is True and one value for $x$ for when the claim is False, right?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Thank you for your interest; but no, it was not what is implied by the statement. "$x < 3$ iff $x < 2$" is meaningless because it sometimes is true (say when $x = 1$) and sometimes is false (say $x = 2.5$). Either "Every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $x < 3$ iff $x < 2$" or "Some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $x < 3$ iff $x < 2$" is meaningful; the former is false because $x = 2.5$ is a counterexample, and the latter is true because $x = 1$ fulfills.

Comment: I understand, but considering "If the truth value cannot be determined, show one example of a value of for which the claim is true, and one example for which the claim is false", I still need to find values of $x$ that makes the expression true or false. Yes?

Comment: Ah yes, in this sense, of course. By the way, it should be "both" in the previous comment of mine instead of "either ... or". I cannot change it now... :)

Comment: I used $x=2.5$ to show that it would be False. And then I used $x=1$ to show that it would be True.

Answer (score 2):

What a strangely-worded question.

With $x$ indeterminate, in which case the statement should really be preceded by "$\forall x \ldots$", the statement is false because of counterexamples such as $x=2.5$.

If $x$ is given (which would be rather odd, but still ...), the statement would be true if $x<2$ (the statement becomes $T\iff T$) or if $x\ge 3$ (the statement becomes $F\iff F$); otherwise, when $2\le x<3$ and the statement becomes $F\iff T$, it is false.

Answer (score 1):

You have written a biconditional statement:

$$x<3\Leftrightarrow x<2$$

This implies that:

$$x<3\Rightarrow x<2,\ x<2\Rightarrow x<3$$

A biconditional statement can only be true if the two quantifiers are either **both** true or **both** false.

Our two quantifiers are $x < 3$ & $x < 2$, respectively.

Therefore, because we are dealing with inequalities, we have to divide this into cases:

Case $1$: $x < 2$:

If $x < 2$, it would make the two quantifiers true, therefore making the overall biconditional true.

Case $2$: $2 \le x < 3$

If $2 \le x < 3$, Then it would make the first quantifier true, but the second one false. Therefore, the biconditional is false.

Case $3$: $3 \le x$

If $3 \le x$, it would make the two quantifiers false, therefore making the overall biconditional true.

Hope this clarified your question.